# Some bounty / featured-question history is lost or invisible.

Tags: discussion, bounty, edit-history

Bounty offers and awards are public attributes of a question but their history is not recorded in the edit trail of a posting.  This is a minor point, but in theory the information should be kept visible somewhere, should it not?  That data may also have a future use, as it is likely that eventually there will be ongoing retrospective collections such as "best of math.SE" and one such might be a "recently featured" or "recent bounty awards" list.

Note that some threads have a more complicated bounty history than a single offer and award, and in others where a bounty is offered but not awarded, the offer disappears from history after expiration.

Comment: Feature-requests for the software itself should better be raised on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: I'm posting here to see whether there is enough interest to make it a feature-request.  I think it would make sense eventually but is a low priority for now compared to things like multidimensionalizing the ratings.

Comment: A related request on meta.stackoverflow.com is [status-planned] (but it has been [status-planned] for 11 months): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history

Answer (score 5):

[This was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history/67747#67747) one day after Tsuyoshi Ito posted his link.  Bounties now show up in the revision lists.

There is also the [recent addition of a bounty tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53414/history-list-of-bounty-questions-opened-by-an-individual-user) on user pages.